# Add custom hover functionality to a jquery widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to add hover functionality to a jQuery widget. This is what I have but it doesn't work. What have I missed? What I am hoping to do is expand the title to the long title

I put it in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/7JHXt/

```
(function ($) {

$.widget('nt.textline', {
    options: {
        title: { short: 'XXX', long: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'},
        text: 'Some text'
    },

    widgetEventPrefix: 'textline:',

    _create: function () {
        this.element.addClass('textline');

        // chart container
        this._container = $('<div class="textline-container"></div>')
            .appendTo(this.element);

        this._setOptions({
            title: this.options.title,
            text: this.options.text
        });
    },

    _destroy: function () {
        this.element.removeClass('textline');
        this.element.empty();
        this._super();
    },

    _setOption: function (key, value) {
        var self = this,
            prev = this.options[key],
            fnMap = {
                'title': function () {
                    createTitle(value, self);
                },
                'text': function () {
                    createText(value, self);
                }
            };

        // base
        this._super(key, value);

        if (key in fnMap) {
            fnMap[key]();

            // Fire event
            this._triggerOptionChanged(key, prev, value);
        }
    },

    _triggerOptionChanged: function (optionKey, previousValue, currentValue) {
        this._trigger('setOption', {type: 'setOption'}, {
            option: optionKey,
            previous: previousValue,
            current: currentValue
        });
    },

    _hoverable: function () {
        alert('here')
        e.css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
});

function createTitle(title, widget) {

    // Clear existing
    widget._container.find('.title').remove();

    var t = $('<div class="title"></div>')
        .text(title.short);

    widget._container.append(t);

}

function createText(text, widget) {

    // Clear existing
    widget._container.find('.text').remove();

    var t = $('<div class="text"></div>')
        .text(text);

    widget._container.append(t);

}

})(jQuery);
$('.textline').textline({});
```

Comment: you can't just paste all your code and expect us to figure out what's wrong with it, explain what you're trying to accomplish, tell us how it's failing, are you getting any errors in the browser's console? also it's always preferable if you provide us with an example to test the code, in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) maybe

Comment: a good idea. I'm on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SEE THIS WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7JHXt/1/)

You don't even need to worry about the _hoverable property here, you can just use _hover.

Basically, add this inside your _create method to specify the events:

```
        this._on(this.element,
        {
            mouseenter:"_hover",
            mouseleave:"_hover"
        });
```

And then set the event handlers for the predefined events you set in the create method anywhere in the widget object that also contains that _create method.

```
    _hover: function (e) {
        var title = $(this.element).find('.title');

        if(e.type == "mouseenter")
        {
             title.text(this.options.title.long);     
        }

        if(e.type == "mouseleave")
        {
            title.text(this.options.title.short);
        }

    }
```

Theres a great tutorial **[HERE](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1)** that shows you how to do a lot of other stuff with the jquery ui widget factory.